# try{} catch{} cURL connection refused PHP

Tags: php, exception, curl, try-catch

I use curl to request data from a server. Because I need to perform a check if the server is responding. I use this code at the moment:

```
    private function getAddress(){

    //...prepare connection
    try{
        $response = $client->sendCommand($command);
        return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        return json_encode([
            'errors' => 'server offline',
            ]);
    }
```

Using this code I get this error when server is offline, my `catch{}` block won't get executed.

> Exception in CurlDriver.php line 76:
>   Failed to connect to IP port PORT: Connection refused

Comment: Could you tell us which line is 76 in your code?
by the way cURL does not throw exceptions, it is a thin wrapper for the C library it binds to.

Comment: this is the server issue, port is not available

Comment: Yes I know this is caused by server, but I would need to catch this event, when service is offline.

Comment: I think PORT is a constant, please make sure it is defined.